# Disable all A(URL) elements in DIV

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have this html code

```
<div>
<p>MY Text <a href="url">Text</a>
</p>
</div>
```

I need to use CSS or jQuery disable all A (link) elements in a DIV, when the user moves the mouse over the word: "Text", I want the URL to be inactive so they can't click on it. How do I do that?

Comment: Can you please, edit your question with some more clear english? It will help all and in fact help yourself.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To prevent an anchor from following the specified HREF, I would suggest using preventDefault():

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('div a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });
})
```

See: [**`Event Object`**](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/jQuery.Event#event.preventDefault.28.29)

or

```
$("div a").click(function(){
                alert('disabled');
                return false;

});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('div').hover(function(){
        $(this).find('a').attr('disabled','disabled');
    },function(){})
});
```

But why would you do that?

Answer (score 0):

- Remove the href attribute; or
- Bind an onClick handler which returns false;